# Django admin list_filter - dropdown widget

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-admin

I can change `list_filter` of related object to dropdown. The problem is when I want to filter on related objects of related object:

```
class Match(Model):
    team = models.ForeignKey('Team'...)
    away_team = ... (doesn't matter)

class Team(Model):
    country = models.ForeignKey('Country'...)
```

When I want to filter `Match` objects by `Team`, I do:

```
list_filter = ['team__country']
```

To `dropdown` this filter, I use https://github.com/mrts/django-admin-list-filter-dropdown:

```
 list_filter[('team',RelatedDropdownFilter)]
```

When I want to filter `Match` objects by `Country` of their `Team`:

```
list_filter = ['team__country']
```

But when I want to make dropdown from this filter, it doesn't work:

```
list_filter = [('team__country',RelatedDropdownFilter)]
```

It looks the same as there were not `RelatedDropdownFilter` specified.

**RelatedDropdownFilter**

```
class RelatedDropdownFilter(RelatedFieldListFilter):
    template = 'django_admin_listfilter_dropdown/dropdown_filter.html'
```

**Template**

```
{% load i18n %}
<script type="text/javascript">var go_from_select = function(opt) { window.location = window.location.pathname + opt };</script>
<h3>{% blocktrans with title as filter_title %} By {{ filter_title }} {% endblocktrans %}</h3>
<ul class="admin-filter-{{ title|cut:' ' }}">
{% if choices|slice:"4:" %}
    <li>
    <select style="width: 95%;"
        onchange="go_from_select(this.options[this.selectedIndex].value)">
    {% for choice in choices %}
        <option{% if choice.selected %} selected="selected"{% endif %}
         value="{{ choice.query_string|iriencode }}">{{ choice.display }}</option>
    {% endfor %}
    </select>
    </li>
{% else %}

    {% for choice in choices %}
            <li{% if choice.selected %} class="selected"{% endif %}>
            <a href="{{ choice.query_string|iriencode }}">{{ choice.display }}</a></li>
    {% endfor %}

{% endif %}
</ul>
```

Do you know what should I do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your template is checking whether or not there are more than 4 choices:

```
{% if choices|slice:”4:” %}
```

My guess is that there are not more than four choices in the test data that you are viewing.

Simply remove that check and always use the `<select>` in that block, or add more test data. The choices are built based on existing data, rather than simply including all possible values.

Comment: Oh my god, didn't checked it, thanks, it makes sence.

Comment: @MilanoSlesarik Awesome, and thanks for the quick reply on my prior attempt to answer, which was clearly a misunderstanding of the question on my part.